# WooCommerce request quote for shopping cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want a new button in the Shopping Cart. Just next to the Check Out button.

There are many plugins for this functionality, except they all do it on the product page level. I cannot find a single plugin that handles an customer request for an inquiry/offer or a quote.

Is it possible to change the way the Check Out behaves? Just by adding an extra button that goes to the same page as when you click "Check out". You can then fill your details and do not have to pay, but instead click "Request quote".

Comment: I am not trying to be an ass, but I would suggest you try a basic Google search. I know there are multiple plugins that do this already.

Comment: Hey thanks :-) I am now reworking templates and using hooks to get this working. I'll update this to an answer soon. But there are _no_ plugins doing what I want. All they do is replacing the "Add to cart" button on the _product_ pages......

Comment: Ok, now I understand your question a bit better and can see how the myriad plugins maybe don't suit your needs. It's still kind of off-topic as too broad (as is). If you have a specific "how to" question (ideally with some code you are trying to implement), feel free to edit so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was editing the WooCommerce pages to get a button on the Cart. I also added a custom hidden field 'request-quote' to keep track of an order that was actually an inquiry:

```
// Add custom hidden field to checkout page

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'offerte_checkout_field' );
function offerte_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="offerte_checkbox" style="display:none;"><h2>' . __('Offerte') . '</h2>';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'offerte', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('offerte form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Offerte')
    ), ( isset($_GET['offerte'] ) ? 1 : 0 ) );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Following to that I edited where the email headings and body text. If it was an enquiry I edited the emails.

I used the following hooks to archive that:

- woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order
- woocommerce_email_subject_new_order
- woocommerce_email_heading_new_order
- woocommerce_email_heading_customer_processing_order